# How to set a custom color on the chakra UI colorScheme prop

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I want to pass a custom color to the colorScheme prop but it's not working. An answer on stack overflow suggests I set custom colors in the theme object and then pass that to the chakraProvider, but I don't want to have chakras theme on my application. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, chakraUI colorScheme is always XXX.500, where XXX can be blue, red or any color defined in the theme.
To change the color scheme to a custom color. set your brand color in the theme,

```
const theme = extendTheme({ 
colors: {
    brand: {
      100: "#f7fafc",
       ...
       500: "#12abef"
      // ...
      900: "#1a202c",
    },
  },
})
```

Then in your component, set the color scheme to the brand color (it will default to the brand.500 hex value).

```
<Button colorScheme="brand">...</Button>
```